# Call a method in parent class

Tags: c#, oop, class

So here is my setup and the comment shows what I wish to do:

```
class Process
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Here I want to call Parent.MethodToCall()
    }
}

class Controller
{
    Process c = new Process();

    void MethodToCall()
    {
    }
}
```

Now the `Controller.MethodToCall()` will be called many times throughout the lifecycle of the `Process` class.

It is only the parent method that needs to be called so I believe that using an `event` would be a bit wasteful as I will never be removing the handler and there would only be one invocation.

So the way I am currently using to get around this is like follows:

```
class Process
{
    public Func<void> Method { get; set; }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        Method();
    }
}

class Controller
{
    Process c = new Process() { Method = MethodToCall }

    void MethodToCall()
    {
    }
}
```

First off, the syntax might not be perfect, I quickly knocked it up in notepad.

My question: What is the best way to achieve what I want because what I am doing looks quite messy to be?...or am I thinking about this completely the wrong way in terms of design?

Essentially what I want to do is call a method in the Controller class without making it public, because if it is public, I could simply pass the Controller as a parameter to the Process.

Comment: How about inheritance? Child : Parent

Comment: Parent/Child names make us to think about inheritance and it's not the case otherwise you can simply make it protected (or...it is?). Best solution (if a delegate isn't what you want) may involve an interface (and it's the only case you can even have private inheritance) but you should describe the **domain**...what's better in one case may not be good in another (and you won't get 1000 answers about how to call a method...)

Comment: I agree..based on either scenario `Children` can have `Multiple `Parents` and `Parents` can have `Multiple` `Children` more information about how the OP intends to use or is using would be most beneficial to the rest of us in regards to providing the best answer

Comment: Edited, sorry, this isn't an inheritance question.

Comment: Just use a System.Action for your property Method. Controller can set it to its own method or to a anonymous delegate (or to whatever you may need). With more informations there could be a better solution but this should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Child
{
    Parent parent=null;
    public Child(Parent p)
    {
      parent=p;
    }
    void SomeMethod()
    {           
        parent.MethodToCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: The "parent" reference is not declared in the Child class.

Comment: who edited my code? and then down vote? I had this code! Shame on those who deleted my code and down vote!

Comment: Not me, I think it's a good alternative if there was a reference to parent

Comment: so bad, I was formmating my code, and some one is doing so bad to wrongly delete my code. What is he doing? and why? :)

Comment: Where is the rest of your code `David` I see the Child Class but not the `Parent Class`

Comment: just snippet, and I did not include full source code, you can infer from the context. Good luck!

Comment: See this is, again, something I wanted to avoid as you would have to make the method public, as I said in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a good example of how to do that

```
class Child : Parent
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        base.MethodToCall();
    }
}

class Parent
{
    Child c = new Child();

    protected void MethodToCall()
    {
        c.MethodToCall();//not sure if you are wanting to call c.MethodToCall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in OOP terms the correct answer would be the following:

```
class Child : Parent
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        base.MethodToCall();
    }
}

class Parent
{
    protected void MethodToCall()
    {
       // protected methods are accesible from
       // descendants and private from outside
    }
}
```

But you can always avoid inheritance, using [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_pattern)

Comment: Children can have more than one Parent though. I don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: this is not multiple Inheritance where do you see that..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I'm trying to understand the comment made by AshBurlaczenko

Comment: Same here..LOL his comment doesn't make sense you are doing `SINGLE Inheritance` there is only one `:` and no additional `,` to truly show that you are using single Inheritance

Comment: LOL that's because he probably doesn't understand basic `OOP Concepts` your answer looks fine to me I am going to upvote your answer being that we pretty much have the same answer..I just posted one with the Child.FunctionToCall

Comment: Daniel Thx I was beginning to thing I forgot about how to Inherit..LOL happy coding my friend

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially rolling your own events.  Internally, event handlers are just delegates attached to the event, with the one difference that only the owner of the event can raise it.